# MySQL DELETE space release

Tags: mysql, innodb, information-schema

I've learned that execute DELETE sql in mysql will not release space, so i do an experiment about it.

During the experiment, i find when my data size is large(about 20000 rows), i delete half of the rows, the data length is not reduced.
But when my data size is about 1000 rows, i try to delete half of the rows. Unexpectedly the data length will be reduced.

It's really confusing. I have search a lot about this problem, but got nothing. What's the reason?

My MySQL version is 5.6

Comment: Are the tables InnoDB?  What is the setting of `innodb_file_per_table`?  How are you measuring the 'release'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InnoDB table statistics are not updated every time you DELETE. So the `data_length`, `index_length`, `rows`, `average_row_length` and `data_free` may not describe the precise state of the table at all times.

You might like to read:

- https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/10/06/when-does-innodb-update-table-statistics-and-when-it-can-bite/
- https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/09/11/updating-innodb-table-statistics-manually/

Even after the table stats are updated, they are not exact. They are estimates based on a limited sample of the table.

---

It should also be mentioned that the size of a tablespace file remains at its high-water mark, even if the data_length is reduced. The difference is space that is part of the file on your filesystem, but it is not occupied by data or indexes anymore. InnoDB should reuse that "free" space within the tablespace before it expands the file further.

Comment: After the update of the stat, it may be not exact, but this shows the data length is definitely reduced, and it's conflict for "delete will not release space".It's really confused for me

Comment: @bjwzds - Did `Data_free` and/or `Index_free` go up at the same time?

Comment: Bill -- I don't think either of those links are relevant to Data_length, etc.  Rather, they only apply to Optimizer stats.

Comment: I thought the length figures were updated at the same time as the other sampled stats for the index cardinality. Cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-statistics-estimation.html